# Create a dictionary w/ list comprehension from a file

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Say I have this code:

```
someDict = {}
for line in open("example.txt"):
  key, val = line.strip().split(",")
  someDict[key] = val
```

with example.txt being two pieces of data on each line, separated by a comma, for example:

```
one,un
two,deux
three,trois
```

etc.

This works in making a dictionary, however I am curious if this could be accomplished in one line (eg with list/dictionary comprehension). Is this possible, or an otherwise shorter/easier way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) and the [`dict()` callable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

```
with open('example.txt') as fileobj:
    someDict = dict(line.strip().split(',', 1) for line in fileobj)
```

I limited the splitting to just once; this allows the value to contain commas and not break the expression.

The `dict()` callable takes a sequence of (key, value) pairs, so splitting a line to exactly two elements satisfies that requirement exactly.

I used a [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to handle the file object; it makes sure the file is closed again after reading has completed or an exception is raised.

It could be done with a dictionary comprehension as well, but that usually gets quite ugly as you'd have to use an additional single-element loop to extract the key-value pair, or split the line twice.

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome. Thanks for such a clear and concise answer explaining why you did what!